# Isomorphic elementary substructure with equal predicates, and stronger(?) lowenheim skolem

Tags: model-theory

Suppose $T$ is a $\lambda$ categorical theory in a language with a unary predicate $P$, and let $\lambda \geq L(T)$. Let $M, N$ be models of $T$ of cardinality $\lambda$, and $M \prec N$ (proper) such that $P^M = P^N$ and $P^M$ infinite.

Then prove that there is $M^* \vDash T$ such that $|P^{M^*}| = \lambda$ and $|M^*| = \lambda^+$

$T$ is complete thanks to categoricity, and thus $M, N$ are isomorphic. To be honest I don't have much more than that. I'm not sure what $M, N$ have to do with it all. I was thinking that the existence of a model with an infinite predicate could let me apply compactness but that's clearly not it given all the info about $P^M = P^N$ and so on. The fact that we have both an elementary extension *and* an isomorphism doesn't mean much to me either. There seems to be a lot of parts here and I'm not sure what role most of them play.

Comment: By the way, the pair of models you are describing is called a Vaughtian pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $M$ is of cardinality $\lambda$ and $T$ is $\lambda$-categorical, it follows that $M$ is $\lambda$-saturated. In particular, $P^M$ has cardinality $\lambda$.

Thus, it suffices to find a strictly increasing elementary chain $(M_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda^+}$ such that $M_0=M$ and for each $\alpha$, we have $P(M_\alpha)=P(M)$ and $\lvert M_\alpha\rvert=\lambda$. If I'm not mistaken, this chain can be constructed using the hypothesis, by straightforward induction. Categoricity is used to ensure that you still have an isomorphic structure at the limit steps.

Comment: Hm it seems I was missing some of the prerequisites for this question. I think your answer makes sense mostly. Except I don't see how the induction would work at the successor steps? Perhaps it is due to some other prerequisites I'm unaware of (something to do with saturation?)

Comment: Is the construction of the elementary chain as simple as compactness + lowenheim skolem? And also using $\{\neg P(c_i) : i \in \lambda \}$ where $c_i$ are new constant symbols in our compactness argument, to ensure $P^{M_\alpha} = P^M$?

Comment: @ArithmeticArthritis: Yes, that is one way to do it, although rather than Lowenheim-Skolem, you should use the Tarski-Vaught test to ensure that the constants form a model (Henkin style). If you know about strongly homogeneous models, though, the more intuitive way to see the solution is to think first of a $\lambda^+$-strongly homogenous model $\bar M$ containing $N=M_1$ and apply an automorphism of $\bar M$ which extends the isomorphism $M\to M_\alpha$. Then $M_{\alpha+1}$ will be the image of $N$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do have one last question though if you don't mind. It is said that if $N, M$ are of _arbitrary_ cardinality (but all other information about them stays the same), we may assume without loss of generality that they are actually both of cardinality $\lambda$. I don't see why this should be true. Do you mind giving a hint.

Comment: @ArithmeticArthritis: Sure. Just consider $N$ with an additional predicate for $M$, find an elementary extension in which the smaller model (given by the predicate) has cardinality at least $\lambda$, then add constants for $\lambda$ elements of the smaller model and apply Löwenheim–Skolem, then forget the new predicate and the new constants.